# TeeChart / Android / Oxygene

Tags: java, android, teechart, oxygene

I have downloaded the Evaluation version of TeeChart for Android and I want to use it within an app developed using RemObjects Oxygene.

If I create a simple hello world app using the default template and create a new chart using

```
var chart: TChart := new TChart(self);
```

within the MainActivity's onCreate method.  When the app starts the following exception is thrown:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can''t find resource for bundle ''com.steema.teechart.languages.languages_en_GB'', key '''''
```

There are no accompanying files beyond the JAR file for TeeChart.  Have I missed anything obvious?

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: I arrived at the same error than you (well, I got `languages_en_US` instead of `languages_en_GB`). I'm still not sure about how to get past this. I see you are discussing it with RemObjects here: http://talk.remobjects.com/t/oxygene-and-teechart/3915/8

Comment: I obtained a private beta build from RemObjects that has now fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

RemObjects provided me a beta build of Oxygene that addresses this issue.